# Machine Learning Algorithm does not work after Vectorizing a feature that is of type text

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I am trying to classify and my features are a combination of words, number and text. I am trying to vectorize the feature that is of type text but when I run it through a classifying algorithm it throws the following error.

> line 51, in 
>       classifier.fit(X_train, y_train.values.ravel())
>
> > ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Below is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from io import StringIO
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df = df[pd.notnull(df['memo'])]
df = df[pd.notnull(df['name'])]


# factorize type, name, and categorized account
df['type_id'] = df.txn_type.factorize()[0]
df['name_id'] = df.name.factorize()[0]
df['categorizedAccountId'] = df.categorizedAccount.factorize()[0]

my_list = df['categorizedAccountId'].tolist()

print(my_list)

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, min_df=5, norm='l2', encoding='latin-1', ngram_range=(1, 2), stop_words='english')
memoFeatures = tfidf.fit_transform(df.memo)

df['memo_id'] = pd.Series(memoFeatures, index=df.index)



X = df.loc[:, ['type_id', 'name_id', 'memo_id']]
y = df.loc[:, ['categorizedAccountId']]



X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)



'''print(X_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
print(y_test.shape)
'''
classifier = LogisticRegression(random_state=0)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train.values.ravel())

y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
confusion_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)

print('Accuracy of logistic regression classifier on test set: {:.2f}'.format(classifier.score(X_test, y_test)))
```

And also here are a few rows of my Data. The top row has the labels and the categorized account is the class

```
"txn_type","name","memo","account","amount","categorizedAccount"
"Journal","","ABC.com 11/29/16 Payments",0,207.24,"1072 ABC.com Money Out Clearing"
"Bill Payment","College Tuition Fund","Multiple inv. (details on stub)",164,-207.24,"1072 ABC.com Money Out Clearing"
```

Comment: `memoFeatures` is a sparse matrix. Setting it in a single column of pandas dataframe is not a good idea and is the source of your error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I have implemented some modifications to your code, which I paste here. This snippet goes immediately after you read the csv, and drop the null rows. You have to implement the train_test_split yourself though.

```
df['categorizedAccount'] = df['categorizedAccount'].astype('category')

df['all_text'] = df['txn_type'] + ' ' + df['name'] + ' ' + df['memo']

X = df['all_text']
y = df['categorizedAccount']

X_train = X # Change these four lines for train_test_split
X_test = X # I don't have enough rows in the mock dataset to implement it,
y_train = y # And it returns an error
y_test = y

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()
X_train_transformed = tfidf.fit_transform(X_train)
classifier = LogisticRegression(random_state=0)
classifier.fit(X_train_transformed, y_train)

X_test_transformed = tfidf.transform(X_test)
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test_transformed)

classifier.score(X_test_transformed, y_pred)
```

A few comments though:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
```

Imported once, ok

```
from io import StringIO
```

Unnecessary as far as I can see

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
```

Why do you import it again?

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
```

TfidfVectorizer does the job of both CountVectorizer and TfidfTransformer. From sklearn: "Equivalent to CountVectorizer followed by TfidfTransformer." See [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) for more

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB 
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
```

Not used, do not import.

Additionally:

1) It is not clear what you are trying to do with factorize. TfidfVectorizer automatically performs tokenization for any string of text that you provide it. All columns that you have selected in your original code contain only strings, so it makes more sense to concatenate them and let tfidf do the tokenization, rather than trying to do it yourself.

2) Use the [Pipeline](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) constructor, it will save your life.

3) `X = df.loc[:, ['type_id', 'name_id', 'memo_id']]` This type of splicing looks very bad, just call `df[['column_name_1','column_name_2','column_name_3']]`

4) And remember PEP20, "Simple is better than complex"!

As a last advice, when developing a ML model it's always better to start with something plain and simple, and then develop further once you have something that works.